# Is there something similar to vectors push_back function that you can do with normal arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++17, size

My question is that our professor doesn't allow us to use vectors. So in a case where I don't know how many times user is going to enter something how do I implement that using normal arrays in c++

I am trying to do this with normal arrays

```
vector<int> x; 
x.push_back(users_input);
```

user_input could be an integer user enters
then I should also be able to find it's size

```
    int size = end(x) - begin(x);
```

MY requirement is that I want to add values to this array only when program falls into that switch choice which means I am not sure how many times user decides to come into that switch choice.

I can make an array and initialize it much largely.

```
int arr[1000];
```

But then how do I find the number of elements in it because if I use sizeof it will give me '1000' not the amount of elements that have gotten stored?

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: A C++ class that avoids std vector looks like one that is teaching mostly the C subset of C++.  Which is a bad sign.  Good luck.

Comment: No. "Normal arrays" have a constant size. You can keep track of the maximum index used.

Comment: `int arr[1000]` has 1000 elements. Full stop. If you need a resizable array, you need a different data structure. It could be built around C-arrays under some conditions.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is that our professor doesn't allow us to use vectors.

You might send your professor the following link: [**Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). (Maybe, do it after you passed the course.)

That said, if you are forced to use a C array, you have to consider two things:

1. Allocate the maximum storage which is sufficient for the expected use case.
2. You have to track the number of currently used elements in an extra variable e.g. `size_t n`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void print(int arr[], size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) std::cout << ' ' << arr[i];
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  // 10 is my optimistic assumption to be sufficient large.
  int arr[10] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 2 };
  // remember that 5 elements are in use initially
  size_t n = 5;
  // show array
  print(arr, n);
  // use address of elements where iterators are required e.g. in std::sort
  std::sort(&arr[0], &arr[n]);
  // show sorted array
  print(arr, n);
  
  // how to apply something like std::vector::push_back()
  arr[n++] = -1;
  arr[n++] = 10;
  arr[n++] = 7;
  // show array again
  print(arr, n);
  // use address of elements where iterators are required (alternative form)
  std::sort(arr, arr + n);
  // show sorted array again
  print(arr, n);
}
```

Output:

```
 1 3 5 4 2
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 -1 10 7
 -1 1 2 3 4 5 7 10
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ab5134580cb3353)

Something which must be kept in mind: `n` may not become larger than the size of the array. Otherwise, read/write access would result in Undefined Behavior.
It couldn't hurt to check the size of `n` before applying `arr[n++] =` …

---

As [`463035818_is_not_a_number` commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799381/is-there-something-similar-to-vectors-push-back-function-that-you-can-do-with-no/67800094?noredirect=1#comment119842149_67800094):

Another alternative is, of course, to manage dynamic memory with [**new[]**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (and `delete[]`), which I consider as a pain. Actually, I was under the impression that the C++ standard's consortium did a lot of effort to free the application developers from that pain.
Nevertheless, a lot of professors seem to insist in the fact that the students have to learn this. (I don't like to justice whether it's good or bad. – I myself learnt it that way due to the lack of alternatives in the past.)
However, this site is full of questions with failed attempts…

I preferred to present a simple alternative – according to do things never more complicated than required (also known as [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

Comment: one could also reallocate a dynamically allocated C array when more size is needed than there is capacity, though this will end in reimplementing `std::vector`. I just tripped over "you **have to** [...] allocate maximum storage for typical use case", thats one way but not the only one.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah. I came to the same idea but this would make things more complicated. Managing dynamic arrays without using the std containers is, of course, a pain. Hence, I followed my general principle: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). ;-)

Comment: as OP is specifically asking for `int arr[1000];` "have to" is actually just right